# Finding the p value of Generalized Likelihood Ratio (GLR) test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value, likelihood

In doing a subset test of $H_0: \frac{d_1}{a_1} = ... = \frac{d_{10}}{a_{10}}$ vs $H_1: $ no restriction,

where $d_i$'s are parameters and $a_i$'s are known constants

Suppose a generalized likelihood ratio test is to be done, I have computed the statistic $-2\log\Lambda$ as some function of $X=(X_1, ..., X_n)$ denoted as $T(X)$,

Using Wilk's Theorem, the GLR test is $\mathbf{I}(T(X) > \chi^2_{10}(\alpha))$, where $\mathbf{I}()$ is the indicator function, and the difference in degrees of freedom between $H_1$ and $H_0$ has been found to be 10.

From here, I do not know how to proceed in finding the p value.
My understanding of the p value is it is the smallest size ($\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} E[\phi(\theta)]$) of a test $\phi(\theta)$ to reject $H_0$ based on observed data $X=x$, and the special case for test of simple indicator function form is $pv(x)=\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} Pr(T(X) \geq T(x))$. As long as we know the distribution of $T(X)$, we can substitute real data into $T(x)$ and find the value of $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} Pr(T(X) \geq T(x))$.

However in my example, I can only substitute real data into the left hand side $T(X)$ of the test $\mathbf{I}(T(X) > \chi^2_{10}(\alpha))$, the value of $\chi^2_{10}(\alpha)$ is unknown and is not related to the data. I can try setting $\alpha$ as some common significance level like 0.05, but it does not seem related to the p value.

I am allowed to assume $T(X)$ under $H_0$ as chi-square distribution by choosing a suitable degree of freedom, should I ditch the Wilk's theorem result and actually find $\sup_{H_0} Pr(T(X) \geq T(x))$ where $T(X)$ follows chi square, and $T(x)$ the substituted value with real data? But I am not sure what degrees of freedom to use for $T(X)$ chi square under $H_0$, as I only know the difference between $H_1$ and $H_0$. There are 10 parameters to be tested but the entire likelihood function involves $J > 10$ parameters.
I found the difference by :

(dof without restriction) - (dof restricted) $=J-(J-10)=10$ since the 10 parameters in $H_0$ are specified.

How should the p value be found?

Comment: I cannot see where the value of $10$ comes from, because you invoke only nine linear equalities in $H_0.$  I also do not understand the sense in which you claim the significance level is unrelated to the p-value, because those two concepts are so intimately connected.

Comment: @whuber In fact there is a constraint of $\sum_{i=1}^J d_i = B$, I get the dof becomes 9 if the constraint is $\sum_{i=1}^{10} d_i = B$ as the last one can be deduced by subtraction, however it is not the case here. I said unrelated in the sense that I don't see p-value calculations involve us assigning a significance level, it is independent of $\alpha$ from what I understand.

Comment: That's even more confusing: to which hypothesis does this new constraint apply?  Because you frame your question completely abstractly, in order to be understood correctly you must supply *all* conditions and you must state them with *complete accuracy.*

Comment: @whuber The constraint applies to both hypotheses. How should the p value be computed from the GLR test after applying Wilk's Theorem?

Comment: Since it applies to both, you have at most $9$ df.  The p value is computed as always: refer the statistic to the proper chi-squared distribution.

Comment: @whuber Will you explain how the p value is computed by giving a mathematical formulation? Is my understanding of $pv(x)=Pr_{H_0}(T(X) \geq T(x))=1-cdf(T(x))$ where cdf is that of chi square (df 9 in this case) correct? Also, what is the reasoning behind at most $9$ df? Are you saying the difference in degrees of freedom is $9$ when applying Wilk's Theorem? Since given the likelihood under $H_1$ depends on $J$ unknown parameters, the likelihood under $H_0$ should have $J-10$ after the $H_0$ narrows down the first $10$ parameters. The constraint of sum of $d_i$'s apply to the derivation of $J$.

Comment: @whuber Wilk's Theorem states that in finding $v=p-p_0$ as the approximated chi square df, the $p$ should be the number of unknown parameters that the likelihood function, or joint distribution of sampled random variables, depend on. This is different from the number of unknown parameters stated directly within $H_0$, which is $\leq 10$. A likelihood can depend on a million parameters yet have the hypothesis test only a few. In this case why shouldn't it be 10 instead of 9?

Comment: @whuber You can consider $J$ as a number that is obtained after considering the $\sum_{i=1}^{J+1} d_i = B$ constraint.
For example, let there be $16$ $d_i$'s, the $\sum_{i=1}^{16} d_i = B$ gives us $J=15$, and we are testing whether the first $10$ are equal to some fixed values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141309/discussion-between-algomaniac-and-whuber).